# Looking for sources of online graduate-level education

Tags: graduate-school, online-resource

Can anyone suggest sources of online graduate-level education, as well as some criticism of them? Both free and paid are valid. I'm familiar with these sources:

- [Academic Earth](http://academicearth.org/)
- [MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm)
- [Kahn Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/)
- [NYU Open Education](http://www.nyu.edu/academics/open-education.html)

and I'm curious to know what other resources are available.

Comment: Cloud you be more specific? Currently the question is way, way to broad.

Comment: Do you mean **free** online graduate education?  Lots of universities have online MS programs that charge tuition.

Comment: @JeffE Free and paid.

Comment: Oy.  Okay, in what field(s)?  Computer science?  Economics?  Nursing?  Russian history?  Can you at least narrow it down a _little_?

Comment: Also, do you want criticism of _specific_ venues for online graduate education, or do you want criticism of online education _in general_?  (_Please_ don't say "both"!)  And criticisms about what aspects—educational quality, reputation, intellectual depth/rigor,  schedule flexibility, access to faculty, expected economic payoff, or what?  (_Please_ don't say "all of the above"!)

Comment: @JeffE Haha, the worst part is that i'm curious in all the aspects you suggested.

Comment: Then this is a bad question; I'm voting to close it.  Please consult the [faq], especially the line "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.", and ask something more focused.

Answer (score 6):

A few points:

1. What subject are you looking at? The answer varies significantly if you are not looking at science/math/engineering.
2. Define 'graduate level' because the Khan Academy (Not Kahn) is far from graduate level.
3. [This](http://www.infocobuild.com/education/education.html) is a very good link. I'll paste an excerpt here:

> **MIT OpenCourseWare** : undergraduate and graduate subjects taught at MIT.
>
> **Open Yale** Courses : astronomy, biomedical engineering, history, economics, English, philosophy, physics, political science, and
>   psychology.
>
> **UC Berkeley Webcast** : biology, computer science, electrical engineering, physics, political science, and psychology.
>
> **Stanford Engineering Everywhere**
>
> **NPTEL** basic undergraduate science and engineering courses. The courses include biotechnology, civil engineering, computer science,
>   electrical engineering, electronics and communication, and mechanical
>   engineering.
>
> **McGill Univ. COurses OnLine (COOL)** : chemistry, biology and computer science.
>
> **UCLA BruinCast** offers some free audio/video lectures for certain undergraduate courses from the University of California, Los Angeles
>   (UCLA).
>
> **Open Learning Initiative | Harvard University Extension School** brings free audio/video lectures on topics in computer science,
>   English literature, history, and mathematics.
>
> **Video & Audio | University of Cambridge** offers free access to audio and video lectures from the University's institutions including
>   the Isaac Newton Institute for Mathematical Sciences and the
>   Department of Materials Science and Metallurgy.
>
> **Podcasts from the University of Oxford** provides free access to certain course materials and audio/video lectures on a variety of
>   subjects, including chemistry, engineering, humanities, life science,
>   medical sciences, physics, and social sciences.
>
> **YouTube - UHouston's Channel (University of Houston)** contains lots of video lectures on various subjects: anthropology, chemistry,
>   English literature, history, philosophy, and psychology.
>
> **nanoHUB** Courses contains free educational materials about nanotechnology. The courses cover the following subjects:
>   nanoelectronics, NEMS/nanofluidics, nanomedicine/biology, and
>   nanophotonics.
>
> **Mathematical Sciences Research Institute (MSRI)** provides a large number of free video lectures on a variety of subjects in mathematics
>   and mathematical sciences.
>
> **CERN Document Server** provides a huge collection of text documents and video lectures in particle physics and related areas.
>
> **Department of Mathematics, University of Colorado at Colorado Springs** offers free video lectures on mathematics including
>   calculus, discrete mathematics, linear algebra, differential equations
>   and mathematical statistics. Registration is required to access the
>   lectures.
>
> **Indiana Multimedia Distribution System** offers free audio/video courses and lectures in business and management from Kelley School of
>   Business, Indiana University Bloomington.

The pasted website has links to all the places, alternately, you could simply google the words in bold.

Comment: The meaning is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_school

Comment: I know about Kahn academy being not near graduate level, But it have some topics which I believe are from graduate curricula.

Answer (score 3):

At the graduate level there is less and less 'standardized' material like in undergrad. You might take a few introductory graduate courses that are pretty similar across universities, but then you tend to take very specialized courses (at least in my experiences with fields like math, computer science, and physics; and my answer should be taken as only relevant to those fields). Further, the number one skill you are suppose to learn in grad school seems to be **independence**.

If some specialized course is not offered at your university then the standard procedure is to look for good lecture notes on the websites of experts in that field. These experts usually teach relevant graduate level courses and post their lecture notes online. In fact, some of these lecture note become rather famous:

[What Lecture Notes (in theoretical computer science) Should Everyone Read?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4074/1037)

Then you have to do what *every graduate student has to do*, and that is to *motivate and teach yourself* with the guidance of those lecture notes (and maybe Q&A sites like SE or emails to the relevant experts). Some tricks to make this is easier is to form groups with other graduate students and learn the material together through regular meetings and discussions.

Answer (score 2):

I've found many interesting & diverse lectures in the [Education section of Apple's podcast directory](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/apple-education/id334296685) (I can't verify that link at work, I hope it's correct). While most are undergraduate, some are taught at a higher level, and they're a good resource for when you need to learn a new discipline in grad school.